# Probability of correctly ordering 6 objects

Tags: probability

If you have 6 objects and are tasked with guessing which order they go in, what is the probability that you guess right?

My best guess is that it is 1 in 720. 6*5*4*3*2*1=720

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: What chance do you have of guessing the first one correctly? If you do, what chance do you have of *doing the same* for the remaining five?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

1. How many possible orderings are there?
2. How many of them constitute the desired positive outcome?

What probability is there to get the desired from the total?